# Why does my code print some random numbers insted of "Hello World"?

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << 'Hello World' << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
1869769828
```

What should I do to my code to print `Hello World`?

Comment: strings use `"` in C++, not `'`.

Comment: Attention to detail is very important to be an effective programmer.

Comment: Reminder:  use `'` for single letters, `"` for multiple letters (strings).

Comment: Turn on and do not ignore the warning diagnostics: https://godbolt.org/z/j1o7GPj1d they are the first line of defense against logic errors.